# Typescript Wrap "function asserts foo is type"

Tags: typescript, assert

Let's create two dummy classes and some example code:

```js
class A {
    constructor() {}
}

class B extends A {
    value: number;

    constructor(value: number) {
        super();
        this.value = value;
    }
}


const values: A[] = [new A(), new A(), new B(123)];
const oneOfThem = values[2];

validateB(oneOfThem);

console.log(oneOfThem.value);


function validateB(item: A): asserts item is B {
    if (!(item instanceof B)) {
        throw new Error('wrong type!');
    }
}
```

This code runs perfectly.

The thing is I need to wrap `validateB` with another function:

```js
function validateBWrapper(item: A) {
    return validateB(item);
}
```

But as soon as I use this function instead of `validateB` in the code above, it loses the `asserts ...` info:

[image: error]

**I don't want to copy `asserts item is B` to the wrapper function.** In my actual usage, the wrapping function wraps a function it gets a parameter.

I'm trying to find something similar to `ReturnType<>`, but with `asserts`.

Is there any way to retrieve `asserts` info from a given function?

Thanks!

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=33&pc=2#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8CwAoa7rAPYDsIBcAnAV2Hy0IAoBKRVVDaAX1RZVVEhgCFoBTAB74+OACYx4yNBgBuYEMT4AuaDmIBbAEZ9CAbnrT02PEVLkqchctUbthWlMaMIxAA46a+w0-wALAJYQAHSWitAAvNChfF6MbGwGxgRR8ooQKrAA2gC6EdCZOHwA7nA0ADSqxaXUFYUl3JQAjABMAMzU2V5J+NC4fADyAGYAKr586nnREJnNnQaW-qJgwtwA6oRgru5UfUOj49ReHLgQWCB8QSBYAOaUuyNj6iGpfIcGqIPEOGT+uCkgi2WfAa-mE6gy1BUXB0+BgoPG0EC0F4jgw-kG0EoAEJKPCJv4TGBvnwsBjuNQHAwnOg-IQsCU6tAAKKEOlUADkRTpOGu0HwAE93Fj2dQqeh4gZPt98L8cP9ASt1pttriwRC6N5CHx8MRCHKFksVqqDl4mEA)

Comment: What about something like `const validateBWrapper: typeof validateB = function (item: A) { return validateB(item); }?` If that works for you I'll write up an answer with it and related thoughts

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you are right, `asserts` and `is` are special keywords that help typescript parser to understand our goals when `ReturnType<>` only extracts a type, in case of `asserts` it is `void` and in case of `is` it is `boolean`.

and without saying explicitly that function `asserts` or `value is T` there's no way to inherit it.

The way we have - to open an issue on github and to wait until they add a new utility type for it here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html

Comment: Is there any alternative I can do explicitly in-line code? Something I could write after `validateBWrapper(oneOfThem)` to make sure the rest of the code will know `oneOfThem` is `B`?

Comment: only the way you mentioned: copy-paste `validateBWrapper(item: A): asserts item is B`. without it TS won't recognise it based on a child assertion type.

Comment: I meant when I have a more generic flow, like:
```typescript
const oneOfThem = values[2];
oneOfThem is B;
console.log(oneOfThem.value);
```

Comment: you can define it as a tuple `const values: [A, A, B] = [new A(), new A(), new B(123)];`, then you don't need a check, but I'm not sure whether a tuple fits your code.

Comment: btw, why do you not want to use `validateB` and require only `validateBWrapper `?

Comment: Because in my actual code I don't have `validateB`, I get that function as an argument.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213345/discussion-between-itay-ganor-and-satantime).